# Got Java heap memory error for EXPLODE_OUTER in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
import org.json.{JSONArray, JSONObject}
```

val CAST_AS_ARRAY = (data: String) => {
try {

```
    val jArr = new JSONArray(data)
    var res: Array[String] = Array()
    for (i <- 0 until jArr.length()) {
      res = res :+ jArr.get(i).toString
    }
    res
  
} catch {
  case e: Exception => Array[String]()
}
```

}

```
spark.sqlContext.udf.register("cast_as_array", CAST_AS_ARRAY)

 var df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").option("quote","\"").option("escape","\"").load("FILE_PATH")

df.createTempView("df")

spark.sql("select transport,explode_outer(cast_as_array(`transport`)) from df").show
```

---

I have a CSV file with one column and one row and the file size is **21.6 MB**.
Perform show action on the reading dataframe got JVM Heap memory error [image]

please help me to solve this problem

**Executor Memory 1G**

Comment: How fat is the transport column? are you sure the data is not broken? what is CAST_AS_ARRAY? can you share the function with us ?

Comment: HI @Benny Which is almost 20Mb

Comment: Let's try simple, try instead of the for loop, just return the JsonArray after your casting.
I think the issue is within your UDF but I can't really debug your code, start there and let me know.
Just mark some code out and unmark every iteration.
I think the for loop is problematic.

Comment: Return JsonArray is not possible in UDF.

Comment: `
val CAST_AS_ARRAY = (data: String) => {
    try {
      
        val jArr = new JSONArray(data)
        val res: ArrayBuffer[String] = ArrayBuffer()
        for (i <- 0 until jArr.length) {
          res += jArr.get(i).toString
        }
        res
      
    } catch {
      case e: Exception => Array[String]()
    }
  }`

I'm just converting string column to array column